# downloading files in java in several parts or segments

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, download

I'm trying to download files in java in a multi-segment way (i.e., dividing it to several parts and downloading each part in a separate thread parallelly) but when I use the code below, it seems each thread is downloading the whole file instead of just a part of it but when it finishes, file is downloaded correctly.

note that "downloadedSizeCombined" is sum of all bytes which are downloaded by all the threads and ArrayList "downloadedSize" keeps track of bytes which are downloaded by a single thread.

this method is in class Download which extends SwingWorker.

```
public Void doInBackground() {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARTS; i++) {
        int numOfThePart = i;
        es.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RandomAccessFile file = null;
                InputStream stream = null;

                try {
                    while (Download.this.getStatus() == WAITINGLIST) {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                    // Open connection to URL.
                    HttpURLConnection connection =
                        (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Specify what portion of file to download.
                    int startByte = numOfThePart * sizeOfFile / MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARTS;
                    int endByte = ((numOfThePart + 1) * sizeOfFile / MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARTS) - 1;
                    if (numOfThePart == MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARTS)
                        endByte = ((numOfThePart + 1) * sizeOfFile / MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARTS);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Range",
                        "bytes=" + ((startByte + downloadedSize.get(numOfThePart))) + "-" + endByte);

                    // Connect to server.
                    connection.connect();

                    // Check for valid content length.
                    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
                    if (contentLength < 1) {
                        System.out.println("1");
                    }

                    /* Set the size for this download if it
                       hasn't been already set. */
                    if (sizeOfFile == -1) {
                        sizeOfFile = contentLength;
                    }

                    file = new RandomAccessFile(new File(s.getCurrentDirectory(), getFileName(url)),
                        "rw");
                    file.seek(startByte + downloadedSize.get(numOfThePart));

                    fileLocation = new File(s.getCurrentDirectory(), getFileName(url));

                    stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    while (status == CURRENT) {
                        file.seek(startByte + downloadedSize.get(numOfThePart));

                        byte buffer[];

                        buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

                        // Read from server into buffer.
                        int read = stream.read(buffer);

                        if (read == -1)
                            break;

                        // Write buffer to file.
                        file.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        downloadedSizeCombined += read;
                        downloadedSize.set(numOfThePart, downloadedSize.get(numOfThePart) + read);

                        publish(numOfThePart);
                        while (status == PAUSED) {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    // Close file.
                    if (file != null) {
                        try {
                            file.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    // Close connection to server.
                    if (stream != null) {
                        try {
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not every http server supports the ["Range: bytes=start-finish"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) header this code uses. Maybe that's the reason? (I also doubt that parallel downloading is actually useful since typical servers can saturate a connection with just 1 download)

Comment: I've tested it on servers which support parallel downloading but no luck. it is a project demand so I should implement it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use UDP connection? So if we use DatagramSocket class, it will anyways send the data in packets. Try this.
Will get back on this soon..